# In e-commerce mobile app, Should I put price before product name or after?

Tags: usability, information-architecture, user-centered-design

Which is better from IA perspective and UCD, to put the product name before the product price or after ? 
I noticed that some of apps like instacart, honeybee put the price before and others like Google Express puts the price after the product's name

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the price after product. Since we read from left to read in most languages, keeping the price tag before even displaying your product gives a negative impression. The product should always take priority over price.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, nice question.

For me you need to consider your target buyer expectations on this aspect.
Whether they are more interested in price or in the product. Let's take one examples to elaborate your issue.

If your listings have several different product on the same page then the user's focus will be on the product more so the product name comes before the price.

Now take the second aspect, if you have same kind of product in a page so the price of those products become more important. Hence put your Price tag before the product name/brand.

Now that's my personal logic if I would have to handle this issue I would have done that. but google or instacart might have their own explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely put the product name before the price.

1. Would a user just buy your product because they could afford the price or would they want to know what the actual product is first? Every user will care about what they are purchasing, not everyone will care as much about the price.
2. The majority of sites also list product name before price so I'd keep it the same as what the average user is used to unless there is a large set of data that proves placing the price first will have greater conversions.

Aside from this, you could also do some A/B testing to see which format gives great conversions.